# Is it possible to concatenate a variable name in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to loop `(xsl:for-each)` through a XML and it will return x nodes that have the same element names and node layout.

I would like to create for each node that I encounter and each value I need a logical parameter that I can address seprately. I tried the array approach, but there is no value returned when I address what should be the corresponding element in the array and the variable does has a value but it looks like one long string without any separators.

So I was wondering if I can create numbered variable names on the fly like variable0, variable1, etc.

I tried to use `<xsl:variable name="concat(name, position())" />` but that is not allowed.

Does one know of a way to achieve this or is it absolutely imposible?

thanks

XML data:

```
<page id="11045138">
    <name>SSC NA XML</name>
    <description/>
    <server>reg6699cic01</server>
    <created>2013/11/18 07:16:53 PM</created>
    <adhocmessage/>
    <workgroups>
        <workgroup>
            <name>SSC_NA_BWDO_All</name>
            <agents>17</agents>
            <agentsavailable>2</agentsavailable>
            <agentsloggedin>5</agentsloggedin>
            <longestavailable>00:01:28</longestavailable>
            <longestoutbound>-</longestoutbound>
            <longestinbound>-</longestinbound>
            <longestnonacd>-</longestnonacd>
            <numbernonacd>0</numbernonacd>
            <numberoninbound>0</numberoninbound>
            <numberoninboundinacw>0</numberoninboundinacw>
            <numberonoutbound>0</numberonoutbound>
            <numberonoutboundinacw>0</numberonoutboundinacw>
        </workgroup>
        <workgroup>
            <name>SSC_NA_DR_All</name>
            <agents>10</agents>
            <agentsavailable>0</agentsavailable>
            <agentsloggedin>0</agentsloggedin>
            <longestavailable>-</longestavailable>
            <longestoutbound>-</longestoutbound>
            <longestinbound>-</longestinbound>
            <longestnonacd>-</longestnonacd>
            <numbernonacd>0</numbernonacd>
            <numberoninbound>0</numberoninbound>
            <numberoninboundinacw>0</numberoninboundinacw>
            <numberonoutbound>0</numberonoutbound>
            <numberonoutboundinacw>0</numberonoutboundinacw>
        </workgroup>
    </workgroups>
</page>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//page/workgroups/workgroup">
            <xsl:variable name="foo-elements" select="name"/>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>testing</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    Body Text<br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$foo-elements[position()]"/>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I require is that the data will be displayed as a table that shows these values (and more) like this

```
Data elements [0]             || Data elements [0+1]
Data elements [0+2]           || Data elements [0+3]
                           /      /
Data elements [0+m]           || Data elements [0+n]
```

It might actualy require 3 rows

```
Data elements [0]             || Data elements [0+1]     || Data elements [0+2]
Data elements [0+3]           || Data elements [0+4]     || Data elements [0+5]
                           /      /
Data elements [0+k]           || Data elements [0+l]     || Data elements [0+m]
```

I hope that explains in brief what I am trying to achieve.
I have something that can loop and puts it all underneeth eachother but then the info runs off the wall board that we need to display it on.

Thanks

Comment: The "one long string without any separators" is most likely an XmlNode.  Obviously, I can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: You have tagged your question as `xslt-2.0` but your stylesheet code has `version="1.0"`. Please state clearly whether you want an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution.

Comment: I need it for both Martin hence I tagged it for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a HTML table with a certain number of columns then you can use that with XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 by processing `workgroup[position() mod $row-count = 1]` to create row and `. | following-sibling::workgroup[position() &lt; $row-count]` to create a cell (in a different mode):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="row-count" select="3"/>

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//workgroups"/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workgroups">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*[position() &lt;= $row-count]" mode="th"/>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="workgroup[position() mod $row-count = 1]"/>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="th">
  <th>
    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
  </th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workgroup">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::workgroup[position() &lt; $row-count]" mode="cell"/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workgroup" mode="cell">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<page id="11045138">
    <name>SSC NA XML</name>
    <description/>
    <server>reg6699cic01</server>
    <created>2013/11/18 07:16:53 PM</created>
    <adhocmessage/>
    <workgroups>
        <workgroup>
            <name>SSC_NA_BWDO_All</name>
            <agents>17</agents>
            <agentsavailable>2</agentsavailable>
            <agentsloggedin>5</agentsloggedin>
            <longestavailable>00:01:28</longestavailable>
            <longestoutbound>-</longestoutbound>
            <longestinbound>-</longestinbound>
            <longestnonacd>-</longestnonacd>
            <numbernonacd>0</numbernonacd>
            <numberoninbound>0</numberoninbound>
            <numberoninboundinacw>0</numberoninboundinacw>
            <numberonoutbound>0</numberonoutbound>
            <numberonoutboundinacw>0</numberonoutboundinacw>
        </workgroup>
        <workgroup>
            <name>SSC_NA_DR_All</name>
            <agents>10</agents>
            <agentsavailable>0</agentsavailable>
            <agentsloggedin>0</agentsloggedin>
            <longestavailable>-</longestavailable>
            <longestoutbound>-</longestoutbound>
            <longestinbound>-</longestinbound>
            <longestnonacd>-</longestnonacd>
            <numbernonacd>0</numbernonacd>
            <numberoninbound>0</numberoninbound>
            <numberoninboundinacw>0</numberoninboundinacw>
            <numberonoutbound>0</numberonoutbound>
            <numberonoutboundinacw>0</numberonoutboundinacw>
        </workgroup>
        <workgroup>
            <name>3</name>
        </workgroup>
        <workgroup>
            <name>4</name>
        </workgroup>
        <workgroup>
            <name>5</name>
        </workgroup>
        <workgroup>
            <name>6</name>
        </workgroup>
    </workgroups>
</page>
```

into

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>1</th>
               <th>2</th>
               <th>3</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>SSC_NA_BWDO_All</td>
               <td>SSC_NA_DR_All</td>
               <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>4</td>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>6</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know whether or not you have an example somewhere?

Comment: @NiteOwls, I think you should edit your question with a sample of your input, the data you want and the approach you have, then we can show you an XSLT 2.0 of selecting the data.

Comment: Martin, that actually is what I am looking for, many thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the way you are suggesting. If you tell us what problem you are trying to solve then we can tell you how to solve it.